# for loop inside for loop (separate)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, select

JavaScript beginner here, trying to learn by doing, here I have a code where is two 'for loops', they are for select box, it shows options of select box.
Currently it is working but I want to separate the 'for loops', is there an easy way to have these 2 for loops but not inside each other?

```js
function updatetheselect(data, values) { 
  var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    var Select = document.getElementById("Select"); 
    var option = document.createElement("option"); 
    for (j = 0; j < values.length; j++) { 
       option.textContent += data[i][values[j]] + " "; 
    } 
    Select.appendChild(option); 
} 
}
```

Comment: That code seems wrong. You are creating one option that has a lot of text? SHowing the data would clean it up.

Comment: And "separate" them how? Are you trying to act on a single `select` element, or multiple? If the former, all you could do is refactor out either of the loop bodies (or both). If the latter, you'd need to be more specific.

Comment: @DaveNewton a single select element, now it is working but dont want it to be for loop inside for loop, want it to be two different for loops but doing this same thing

Comment: But... you're indexing off `data` with a value in `values`--you need both loop counters.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah i need both just trying to figure out if its possible to do it with loops not inside each other, if its not i will delete the question

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW This does not look like the OP wants a code review, so why should they post on Code Review?

Comment: @waleedd32 *Why* do you want this? And how does it make sense? You're looping over two collections, and the text context value (as defined by your existing code) requires the use of both indices. One way or the other you need both indices unless you explicitly restructure your data somehow (which would just move where the loop(s) happen).